# Why does read_graphviz in BGL need to be compiled?

Tags: boost-graph

I like boost because most things don't need to be compiled, only included. The vast majority of the BGL is not compiled but the [read_graphviz](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/read_graphviz.html) functionality needs to be built. It seems like most of the [other compiled libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries) in Boost need more information about your hardware. Why would read_graphvis need to be compiled on the machine? Parsing a graph format seems like something that could easily be tackled in a header only include file similar to the rest of BGL.